# PHP SQLite :: Escape double quotes

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to insert user given strings into a sqlite database in a PHP environment.

Since it is not known how many strings (which are devided in a database-row per string), it is not ideal to use prepaired statements, unless there is a way to prepaire a dynamic amount of rows.

So I use a strict way to escape every inserted value in a single place using either the PDO or static escape functions while building the query string.

Examples:

```php
$value = '\''. SQLite3::escapeString($value).'\'';
$value = $pdo->quote($value);
```

Unfortunatly the double-quotes (`"`) are not escaped because they mean something special. Eventhough I thought a string couldn't contain these special characters, they are not escaped in either version.

I know it can be escaped by doubling up de quotes, but I don't want to do heavy lifting if possible for security reasons.

So is there a good way to escape a string properly in PHP?

---

**Edit:**
As per request an example.

I have a table/structure widget which represents different splashtexts/lines. Along the text there are some other properties which are basically settings/metadata bound to that string.

When saving I push the entire table to the server where everything gets stored in a single designated database table.

So in code I basically have an associative array which looks something like:

```php
[
    0 => [
        'text' => 'some "string" containing all kinds of characters \' ',
        'wheight' => 5
        \\ and some other properties
    ], 
    1 => [
        'text' => 'some other @random text',
        'wheight' => 3
        \\ and some other properties
    ], 
]
```

The size of the table is dynamic, so a prepaired statement like `INSERT INTO table VALUES (?,?,?) ;` won't do as there is only room for 3 variables/ a single row. Unless there is a way to allow for a dynamic amount of values.

Comment: You should probably look into using prepared statements here.

Comment: Yup, know about that, how about the dynamic row-count? Any workarounds for that?

Comment: Please give us some proper examples (example data and how you want that data stored in the table). It's unclear what you mean and why _"It is not ideal to use prepaired statements"_ for it.

Comment: I added a more detailed explanation

Comment: If each sub array should be it's own record/row in the database, then this is _exactly_ what prepared statements are made for. Prepare the statement once and call it multiple times but with different values (could be in a foreach loop). If you want to make things easier, you can use PDO for SQLite as well and you'll have many guides explaining how to do it.

Comment: Alright, so the (performance-wise) quicker method of multi-row-insert is than not possible? (there is a lot of database trafic already, so if possible I prefer the performance effecient way). Mutatability/multithread access is not a concern because of the 'transaction' mechanism, so if there is no other way I could go that route I guese

Comment: When you prepare a statement, it becomes much faster than if you did multiple separate queries since the server doesn't need to parse and prepare each request separately. But if performance is a big part of this, then I would say that using SQLite would probably have a bigger impact.

Comment: You can read more how things work "under the hood" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231647/discussion-between-n247s-and-magnus-eriksson).